# How to not write the DocumentRoot to the XML

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf

I'm using EMF, and I created my ecore from XSD.

I notice that the XML that are being saved by the editor have the element DocumentRoot, which is not part of my original XSD. Can I somehow not generate it, so it will not be in the XML files of the editor?

Ido

Answer (score 0):

> If you have no global elements or
>   attributes in your schema, then you
>   won't get a document root.  But of
>   course your schema has not specified a
>   single way to write a document in this
>   case, it's only defined types and
>   stuff that can be used in another
>   schema.  Some schema will need to
>   declare a global element in order to
>   specify the root of a document.

source: [dev.eclipse.org](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/emf-dev/msg00171.html)

> A document root is created if your
>   model has one and you are using the
>   extended meta data option during
>   loading. The document root has
>   features that correspond to each of
>   your global elements, and the
>   particular feature of the document
>   root that's actually set when
>   deserializing will correspond exactly
>   to the root element that appears in
>   the serialization. Using
>   EObject.eContents().get(0) on the
>   document root instance will return the
>   child EObject of the document root,
>   and that child's eContainmentFeature()
>   will correspond to your global
>   element.
>
> It's good to keep in mind that
>   elements correspond to features that
>   that types correspond to classifiers.
>   Since an EClass corresponds to a
>   complex type, having an instance of an
>   EClass (complex type) is not
>   sufficient information to say what
>   element that should be serialized as;
>   that's determined by
>   eContainmentFeature(), so that's why a
>   document root is needed to specify the
>   root element, because without an
>   eContainer there cannot be a
>   meaningful eContainmentFeature().

source: [dev.eclipse.org](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.emf/msg22215.html)

Try the [mailing list](http://emf-dev@eclipse.org).